# Validate Multiple US ZipCode separated by comma

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

In a textbox a user needs to give 5 US Zipcodes separated by comma. 
Now I need to validate it in following way:

```
1st Whether the five words are typed by User must be separated by comma.
2nd Each word is a valid US Zipcode.
```

Yes, there are plenty of regex for US ZipCode validation but in my case I need to do some more with regex which I am not familiar with. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a jquery selector, but you can do `document.getElementById` or whatever.  And you'll need

```
error = false;
var zip_codes = $('input').val().split(',');
if (zip_codes.length!=5) error = true;
else {
    for (i=0; i<zip_codes.length; i++) {
        if (!(/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/.test(zip_codes[i])))
            error = true;
    }
}
```

Basically we split the string on commas, check if there are 5, if so, we check if each thing between commas is a valid zip code.  At the end of the function, if error is true, don't submit the form.  If it's false, you are good to go.